# ClickOnce file associations don't work if the extension is already associated with another program

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, clickonce

How do I create a file association for a file type that already has an associated application?

I can use clickonce to create file associations for extensions that do not already have an application associated with them. However, I cannot get it to work for file types that already have associations.

This works:

```
<fileAssociation extension=".abc" description="abc file" progid="MyApp.abc" defaultIcon="logo.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" />
```

This fails:

```
<fileAssociation extension=".jpeg" description="JPEG image file" progid="MyApp.jpeg" defaultIcon="logo.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" />
```

(I'd like to associate my app with image files, so coming up with my own extensions is not an option)

Comment: Only one app can be the primary association for an extension though Windows does allow multiple _"Open with"_  verbs

Comment: I know . I want to either replace what exists, or present the user with the choice to replace.